# tvos tvml menubartemplate styling

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml

I'm using Apple's TVML MenuBarTemplate.

Is there a way to style the menubar template?

I'm looking to change the background color but can't seem to find anything that works with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible to style the TVML `menuBar` element. See [this post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/67956) from Apple Staff in the tvOS Beta Apple Developer Forum.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still the case? BBC iPlayer seem to have styled their menuBar. Wonder if there's is a custom implementation though?